# How to get download progress info from I.D.Manager to python?

Tags: python, download, status

im working a project lately to get download progress info remotely when im away.
i googled a bit but i couldnt find any useful info. on this issue
im using Internet Download Manager.
please help :/ i appreciate any suggestions
im thinking about making software with python but Also C is Ok. if there is a solution
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know exactly how to do it but you can get IDM download progress( such as Transfer rate, TimeLeft... ) by reading the values of the ListView of Internet Download Manager windows (they call it "hook"? )

Answer (score 0):

i just found idm has log file for every download in its temporary folder im trying to parse information from log file i dunno if it is possible sync.ly get info..but i'll try