# Use IDM(Internet Download Manager) API with python

Tags: python, com

I am trying to use the IDM api through python but I'm completely lost on how i would do this. 
http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/support/idm_api.html

Could someone please help me?
I don't even know if it is possible to do this with python.

Comment: There is a similar post here for hints. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050653/how-to-get-download-progress-info-from-i-d-manager-to-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IDM api seems to be accessible from Visual Basic, which is good, because it means that it supports IDispatch and therefore Python.  You want to use the [comtypes](http://starship.python.net/crew/theller/comtypes/) library.  Using the [VB sample](http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/support/idm_api.html) as a prototype:

```
import comtypes.client as cc
import comtypes

referrer = ""
cookie = ""
postData = ""
user = ""
password = ""
cc.GetModule(["{PUT_UUID_HERE}",1,0])
# not sure about the syntax here, but cc.GetModule will tell you the name of the wrapper it generated
import comtypes.gen.IDManLib as IDMan
idm1 = cc.CreateObject("IDMan.CIDMLinkTransmitter", None, None, IDMan.ICIDMLinkTransmitter2)
idm1.SendLinkToIDM("http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/idman401.exe",
referrer, cookie, postData, user, password, r"C:\\", "idman401.exe", 0)
```

Comment: I tried your solution but I got this error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    idm1.SendLinkToIDM("http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/idman401.exe",ref
errer, cookie, postData, user, password, "C:\\", "idman401.exe", 0)
AttributeError: 'POINTER(IUnknown)' object has no attribute 'SendLinkToIDM'

Comment: @Ramis Fixed answer to use typelibs.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks alot!!! I did have to make some small changes but it works great. :)

Comment: Just to mention, it's better using UUID to load the module: `idm = cc.GetModule(['{ECF21EAB-3AA8-4355-82BE-F777990001DD}', 1, 0])
`. The UUID can be found in Windows register editor by searching the tlb filename.

Comment: Any idea how to pass data to SendLinksArray?

Comment: @AbdullahSaleem Not entirely sure, as I am by no means a Python guru.  However, a web search for 'python safearray' yields this [interesting link](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2001-April/070661.html), which suggests using win32com.server.util.Collection and win32com.server.util.wrap.

Comment: @nn0p Thanks for the UUID. can I ask how did you find it? I got nothing by searching `tlb` in registry editor!

Answer (score 2):

Update document for IDM (Windows):
https://pypi.org/project/idm/

Example code:

```
from idm import IDMan

downloader = IDMan()
url = "http://test.com/test.exe"

downloader.download(url, r"c:\DOWNLOADS", output=None, referrer=None, cookie=None, postData=None, user=None, password=None, confirm = False, lflag = None, clip=False)
```